# transposing a matrix using pointer C

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code that transposes a matrix using pointer and memory allocation.

When I run it, it freezes from the part that produces a matrix with **`rand function`** in the program given below.

So I couldn't check whether two functions( transpose, printMatrix) work.

**What am I doing wrong??**

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

int** transpose (int **matrix, int m, int n);
void printMatrix(int **matrix, int m, int n);

int main (void){
    int rows, cols;
    int r, c;
    int **matrix;

    printf("Number of Rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Number of Cols : ");
    scanf("%d", &cols);

    matrix = (int **)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
    matrix[0] = malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));

    srand(2016);

 //error starts from here
    for( r = 0; r < rows; r++ ){
        for( c = 0; c < cols; c++ ){
            *(*(matrix + r)+c) = rand() % 99 + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Matrix produced with seed number 2016\n");
    printMatrix(**matrix, rows, cols);

    matrix = transpose(**matrix, rows, cols);

    printf("Transposed Matrix\n");
    printMatrix(**matrix, rows, cols);              
}

int** transpose (int **matrix, int rows, int cols){
    int tmp, i ,j;

    if( rows < cols ){
        matrix[0] = (int *)realloc(matrix[0], rows*rows*sizeof(int));
    }
    else if(cols < rows){
        matrix = (int **)realloc(matrix, cols*sizeof(int*));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0 ; j < cols; j++) {
            tmp = *(*(matrix + i) + j);
            *(*(matrix + i) + j) = *(*(matrix + j) + i);
            *(*(matrix + j) + i) = tmp;
        }
    }  
    return matrix;
}
void printMatrix(int **matrix, int m, int n){
    int i, j;

    for( i = 0; i < m; i++ ){
        for( j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
            printf("%3d", *(*(matrix + i )+j) );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: The main question is do you choose `2016` [randomly](https://xkcd.com/221/) ?

Comment: @Stargateur The seed is given as 2016(in the problem). I didn't randomly choose 2016.

Comment: Please see my answer, it responds to your edit!!

Comment: Please, don't destroy answer by editing your question with the fix (incomplete or not).

Comment: @H. Figueiredo Thank you and I edited that as well. I also edited that function's first if statement as Simone Cifani pointed out but it still gives error.

Comment: @HJY what error are you getting? It's working for me. The transpose does nothing to your matrix according to my output, but the program is working.

Comment: @H.Figueiredo the .exe has stopped working message pops after printing out matrix produced by seed number

Comment: @HJY I'm sorry but I not able to reproduce your error, since for me, it's working. Are you using an IDE? Can you provide a screenshot of what's happening? Can you also maybe try to reproduce the error in an online compiler, like [here](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/WGIBSKENXV) (This contains the code I've posted on my answer, and it is working, so check if you've got anything different)

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating a contiguous array of rows * cols * sizeof(int) starting from matrix[0]:

```
matrix[0] = malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));
```

I think that the allocation should be:

```
matrix = (int **)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the below code:

```
matrix = (int **)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
matrix[0] = malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));
```

In the first statement you are trying to allocate a array of pointers. But, in the second statement you are allocating memory to only one pointer. So, when you try to do `*(*(matrix + r)+c)` , it accesses invalid memory.

You should be doing like below:

```
matrix = (int **)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    matrix[i] = malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers stated your problem is in the allocation of memory for the matrix. But your problems don't stop there. You are also passing the value of the matrix when you want a double pointer in your functions.

Please refer to the corrected code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

int** transpose (int **matrix, int m, int n);
void printMatrix(int **matrix, int m, int n);

int main (void){
    int rows, cols;
    int r, c;
    int **matrix;

    printf("Number of Rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Number of Cols : ");
    scanf("%d", &cols);

    matrix = (int **)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
      matrix[i] = malloc(cols*sizeof(int));

    srand(2016);

 //error starts from here
    for( r = 0; r < rows; r++ ){
        for( c = 0; c < cols; c++ ){
            *(*(matrix + r)+c) = rand() % 99 + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Matrix produced with seed number 2016\n");
    //Changed this, you where doing printMatrix(**matrix, rows, cols);
    printMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);

    //Changed this, you where doing matrix = transpose(**matrix, rows, cols);
    matrix = transpose(matrix, rows, cols);

    printf("Transposed Matrix\n");
    //Changed this, you where doing printMatrix(**matrix, rows, cols);
    printMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);              
}

int** transpose (int **matrix, int rows, int cols){
    int tmp, i ,j;

    if( rows < cols ){
        matrix[0] = (int *)realloc(matrix[0], rows*rows*sizeof(int));
    }
    else if(cols < rows){
        matrix = (int **)realloc(matrix, cols*sizeof(int*));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0 ; j < cols; j++) {
            tmp = *(*(matrix + i) + j);
            *(*(matrix + i) + j) = *(*(matrix + j) + i);
            *(*(matrix + j) + i) = tmp;
        }
    }  

}
void printMatrix(int **matrix, int m, int n){
    int i, j;
    for( i = 0; i < m; i++ ){
        for( j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
            printf("%3d", *(*(matrix + i )+j) );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```